# Returning an array of strings - array populated in Promise handler

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, promise

So, if I have code like this in my Ionic/Angular/TypeScript project...

```
let arr: Array<string> = [];
this.databaseProvider.getAllSpecies().then(allSpecies => {
  for(let species of allSpecies) {
    if(species.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword.toLowerCase()) > -1
        || species.latinName.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
      arr.push(species.name + " - " + species.latinName);
    }
  }
});
return arr;
```

...`arr`, of course, will be empty when it is returned, because the `then()` handler has not been executed yet.

Is there any way to return the array of strings from the Promise handler? Currently I have all `species` objects loaded into memory from the database, but I'd rather not have it like that, as there'll be hundreds of them.

The code is a snippet from an [ionic2-autocomplete](https://github.com/kadoshms/ionic2-autocomplete) `getResults()` function, which must return an array of strings, i.e. not another Promise.

Comment: The ionic2-autocomplete docs state that `getResults` is allowed to return a promise (or an observable, or a regular value).

Comment: I just noticed the same thing, but for some reason this does not seem to work in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the a return where your async function is being called. You have to return a Promise or an Observable. It's async so you have to deal with that reality:

```
return this.databaseProvider.getAllSpecies().then(allSpecies => {  <-- Notice "return"

  let arr: Array<string> = [];
  for(let species of allSpecies) {
    if(species.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword.toLowerCase()) > -1
        || species.latinName.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword.toLowerCase()) > -1) 
    {
      arr.push(species.name + " - " + species.latinName);
    }
  }
  return arr;
});
```

Comment: I got it to work by converting the returned Promise into an Observable like this:
`return Observable.from(this.databaseProvider.getAllSpecies().then(allSpecies => { ... return arr; }));`